# How to use settings.xml on xbmc add-ons?

Tags: python, xml, xbmc

I've got my settings.xml file in resources folder in my xbmc add-on and it shows up fine. How do I make my default.py file now read these settings?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out.

You (or rather, I) have to import xbmcaddon and use .getSetting([xml id])

e.g.

```
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon

...

settings = xbmcaddon.Addon(id='script.usb.autoplay')
df = settings.getSetting("defaultfolder")
xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(%s, isdir)" % df)
```

edit: was wrong, now it's right

Comment: Yeah it is. Sorry for taking forever to confirm this. For anyone else that may be confused, that was just the name of my script.

Comment: @manicphase    Can you share content of your `settings.xml`. Also is it possible NOT to show some setting key in GUI? For instance password?